# SageMaker MLOps Project Using Third-party Git Repos - Error in building

Tags: github, amazon-sagemaker

I'm doing some tutorials using the MLOps templates, to create a Sagemaker Project to build, train and deploy with third-party Git repositories using CodePipeline.  Following this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sagemaker-projects-walkthrough-3rdgit.html#sagemaker-proejcts-walkthrough-create-3rdgit.

I have created the connection in CodeCommit settings, and selected my two repositories created in Github, one for modelbuild and one for modeldeploy. When creating the project, I put the urls from github, the name of the repos (in my case, it is organization/modelbuild-repo) and I use the arn of the connection.
However, in the building process, in the seedcodecheckin, I get the following errors:

```
[GitRepositorySeedCodeBootStrapper.main()] ERROR GitRepositorySeedCodeBootStrapper - Seedcode checkin failed: Invalid remote: origin
```

I also get the following exceptions:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NoRemoteRepositoryException: https://codestar-connections.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/git-http/XXXXXXXXXXX/eu-west-1/ff5bf7e3-bee9-4dad-a63d-0374c4a96297/ORGANIZATION/sagemaker-tutorial-3-modelbuild.git: https://codestar-connections.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/git-http/XXXXXXXXXXX/eu-west-1/ff5bf7e3-bee9-4dad-a63d-0374c4a96297/ORGANIZATION/sagemaker-tutorial-3-modelbuild.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found: Not Found
```

These errors are from the build logs from git-seedcodecheckin.

Which I believe it has to do with trying to populate the repository with the modelbuild code.
Anyone has an idea what might be the error?

I have seen similar questions to this, related to policies and the need for them, but I beleive I have the correct ones attached.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the repository either does not exist or you are not passing in the right name.

You can follow the guidelines in this blog - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/create-amazon-sagemaker-projects-using-third-party-source-control-and-jenkins/

Comment: The repository does exist, and the name is correct. It seems that the problem is that Im not the organization owner in the Github organization, so when I try to create the CodeStar connection, it is not being created correctly, since I need to be admin. Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dtconsole/latest/userguide/connections-create-github.html